# SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111)

Tags: php, email, smtp

Im building a site and I need to implement a form sending option, after a lot of research I settled on PHPMAILER. I set my script to work with my gmail address for testing purposes and it works fine, but when I inputted the clients email details it doesnt work.

When I submit the application, this is what i am getting

**SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111)**

I contacted support and verified the port and host, and contacted the client and verified the login info. Is there another reason why it might not be working?

**Update**
 I made a small script that allows me to easily test settings

```
<?php 
require 'classes/class.phpmailer.php';
require 'classes/class.smtp.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true); 
$mail->IsSMTP(); 
try{
    $mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;                     
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  
    //$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";no                
    $mail->Host       = "smtp.domain.com";      
    $mail->Port       = 25;                  
    $mail->Username   = "username";//user@domain.com
    $mail->Password   = "pwd";           
    $mail->AddAddress('alme1304@gmail.com');//RECIPIENT
    //$mail->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');//IDK WHAT 'THIS' IS FOR
    //$mail->AddReplyTo($_POST['email'], $_POST['f_name'].' '.$_POST['l_name']);//FOR THE 'REPLY-TO' FIELD
    $mail->Subject = 'test email';
    $mail->MsgHTML('test_email');

    $mail->Send();
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
    echo $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
    echo $mail->Host;
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($mail);
    echo '</pre>';

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage(); //Boring error messages from anything else!
}
```

Comment: The client is usually wrong...and support is incompetent (mostly).  Past that, verify no firewall settings are blocking your connection.  Also make sure encryption setting is accurate

Comment: @AaronW. how can I check the settings?

Comment: Could you register for a free mailtrap account and test your code with their setup?

Answer (score 1):

I have had experiences with hosts who claim you can use smtp.domain.com yet you cannot. Instead of smtp.domain.com, use the hosting provider's SMTP servers (you can usually get these from their knowledge base or support)

Also verify the port, many do not use 25 but may use 26, or some other (get from knowledge base or support)

We may be of better assistance if you let us know who the hosting provider is

Comment: the host is hostway.com (help center http://help-sp.hostway.com/docs/guidebook/frame_web.htm), every setting there has been confirmed either by the client, customer support or their help docs

Comment: Can you try the SMTP settings that you are using for your application in MS Outlook and verify that they actually work and you can send email

Comment: I could of but since I never use those programs i was unsure of where it would start picking up older emails

Comment: You can either create a new email address (if you can) to test out whether the connection is valid, and MS Outlook (or any other email client) allows you to test email address settings. The idea is to isolate the root cause by making sure the Hostway SMTP settings are correct

Comment: that did the trick. I used thunderbird to check the login info (which was correct), but turns out the customer rep gave me the wrong port AND smptauth