# Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Connection refused #111]

Tags: laravel-5.6

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com MAIL_PORT=587 MAIL_USERNAME=sample@gmail.com MAIL_PASSWORD=passowrd MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Its working fine on local but on the server its not working and gives me this error:

`Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Connection refused #111]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9543511/smtp-error-failed-to-connect-to-server-connection-refused-111)

Comment: Can you connect with telnet to port 587? Eg. `telnet smtp.gmail.com 587`? A lot of hosts block sending of emails with a firewall to prevent spam.